# flot dynamically defining multiple data with labels

Tags: javascript, flot, dynamically-generated, series

I've read at least half a dozen other questions about doing this, and I can't figure out how mine is different: http://jsfiddle.net/JakobJingleheimer/Z5UFg/1/

I added a function `LoadGraph.check_data` which I run from the console. The data that it output after running `load_data(1,"199 Water St",7);` is:

```
#mine
[ { label:"coffee",  data:[ [1659] ] },
  { label:"cocoa",  data:[ [717] ] },
  { label:"tea",  data:[ [206] ] }
]
```

That looks exactly the same to me as [the example in the doc](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) (just above *Plot Options*):

```
#doc example
[ { label: "Foo", data: [ [10, 1], [17, -14], [30, 5] ] },
  { label: "Bar", data: [ [11, 13], [19, 11], [30, -7] ] }
]
```

I also tried modelling my structure after [SO answer 5661134](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5661134), but that didn't fly either (exact same outcome as seen in the fiddle).

The 2nd graph in the fiddle should either have 3 bars next to each other or (better yet) have the 3 bars stacked on top of each other.

**UPDATE**: I added an x-value to get the following (but it still doesn't work, fiddle):

```
#http://jsfiddle.net/JakobJingleheimer/Z5UFg/3/
[ { label:"coffee",  data:[ [7, 1659] ] },
  { label:"cocoa",  data:[ [7, 717] ] },
  { label:"tea",  data:[ [7, 206] ] }
]
#http://jsfiddle.net/JakobJingleheimer/Z5UFg/2/
[ { label:"coffee",  data:[ [0, 1659] ] },
  { label:"cocoa",  data:[ [1, 717] ] },
  { label:"tea",  data:[ [2, 206] ] }
]
```

If I take out the object-ness (eg, the labelling), it works (but I'll need to figure out why `f_opts.series.stack=true` doesn't work—I think, since all 3 bars are blue, it's treating all three as the same series): [v4](http://jsfiddle.net/JakobJingleheimer/Z5UFg/4/)

**UPDATE 2** Are these supposed to be in 2 different places? By that I mean should that label+data array-object be in the options object and the data also be in the data array? The documentation is kind of difficult to figure out because it never says what the parent object is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5UFg/20/) might be what you're trying to do.

The problem was in your treatment of `f_data` as a single object {} instead of an array of objects, specifically series objects. (You got around this by forcing it into an array in the plot call with `[f_data]`, but this limits you to a single series.). What you want to do instead of setting `f_data = tmp` is instead push a complete series object into `f_data` with `tmp` as its `data` array:

```
f_data.push({label:cat, stack:true, data:tmp});
```

Each series object (each element in your `f_data` array) has its own data and label, as you can see in my example.

There were two reasons why you weren't seeing any stacking working:

1. You need to include the [jquery.flot.stack.js](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js) file to get stacking functionality. (I've added the linked resource in the fiddle.)
2. Stacking only makes sense with multiple series. Your "depth" view was adding 3 overlapping data points to a single series, rather than creating 3 individual series with 1 data point each.

I believe my example achieves the result you were aiming for. Let me know if I am mistaken.
I've tagged new lines I added with //NEW to highlight the changes.

Comment: Yes! OMG you're amazing—thank you. I figured #2 was happening and was a problem, but I couldn't figure out how to fix it ^^,

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that your datapoints consist of only one value, while Flot requires [x, y] pairs.  Check out the [Data  Format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format) section of the docs for more info.

Edit: It also looks like your call to $.plot uses `[f_data]` even though f_data is already an array of series.  It looks like that's the current cause of your problems.

If you run into further problems you should really try to cut down your code to a simpler example and work up from there.  This has turned from a question into a debugging session.

Comment: I tried giving it a second data-point, but the 3 pairs share the same x-value, which flot also doesn't seem to like. I tried adding it for the second graph (wasn't working and still didn't work), and when I tried to add a label in the same way to the first graph (which was working), it broke.

Comment: If you want them stacked, take a look at the stacking example on the examples page.

Comment: I can worry about stacking later.

Comment: I updated the question with some more details about what I tried. It's definitely the object-ness (labelling).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how this works. I had originally mentioned in my question that I had ready the documentation and even pulled the example from it and posted it with my question; so responding to say I should the documentation is not helpful in the least.